# Cases where 'this' is the global Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm playing around with different ways to call a function that is an attribute of an Object in Javascript and looking at which type of calls set 'this' to be the Object and which set 'this' to be the Global Object.

This is my test code:

```
var foo = {
  bar: function(){ 
    console.log('this:' + this);
  }
}

console.log('calling foo.bar()');
foo.bar();

console.log('\ncalling (foo.bar)()');
(foo.bar)();

console.log('\ncalling f=foo; f.bar()');
f = foo; f.bar();

console.log('\ncalling f=foo.bar; f()');
f = foo.bar; f();

console.log('\ncalling (f=foo.bar)()');
(f = foo.bar)();
```

And this is the result:

```
calling foo.bar()
this:[object Object]

calling (foo.bar)()
this:[object Object]

calling f=foo; f.bar()
this:[object Object]

calling f=foo.bar; f()
this:[object global]

calling (f=foo.bar)()
this:[object global]
```

My question is, why does `f=foo.bar; f();` and `(f=foo.bar)();` assign 'this' to be the Global Object

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key of knowing the implicit behavior of `this` on function calls, relies on knowing how the [*Reference Type*](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.7) woks.

The *Reference Type* consists of two components (in ECMAScript 3), the *base object* and the *property name* (in ECMAScript 5, it has a third component the *strict* flag -I will talk about strict mode later- <sup>(1)</sup>).

When a [function is invoked](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.2.3), the `this` value is determined implicitly by getting the base object of the reference (by the internal `GetBase` operation).

For example, in the `foo.bar` reference, the *base object* is `foo` and the *property name* is `"bar"`:

```
foo.bar(); // `this` will point to `foo`
```

When you do an assignment, the reference is lost, we don't have anymore a *base object* and a *property name*, we just have a **value**:

```
(f=foo.bar)(); // `this` will point to the global object
```

It doesn't happen only with assignments, it happens with other operations that use the internal [`GetValue`](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.7.1) operation:

```
// `this` will point to the global object    
(0, foo.bar)();   // The Comma Operator
(0 || foo.bar)(); // Binary Logical Operators
(1 && foo.bar)();
// etc..
```

It doesn't happens for example if you surround a *reference* with parentheses (formally called [The Grouping Operator](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.1.6)):

```
(foo.bar)(); // `this` will point to `foo`
```

The Grouping Operator (again, the parentheses ;) doesn't use `GetValue` internally, this was designed in that way because the `typeof` and `delete` operators are allowed to work with *parenthesised expressions*:

```
delete (foo.bar);
```

If the grouping operator used `GetValue`, the `delete` operator would be unable to get a *base object* where to remove the property `bar`.

Returning to the implicit `this` value, there are some tricky cases, for example, using the `with` statement:

```
with (foo) {
  bar(); // `this` will refer to `foo` !
}
```

As you can see, invoking `bar();` inside the with block, will still bind the `this` value to the `foo` object.

The `this` value isn't set from the *reference*, it comes from the current *Environment Record* (I'll maybe write something about it later) introduced by the `with` statement.

Also, as you may note, for *non-references*, the `this` value will point to the global object, for example:

```
(function () {})(); // this will point to the global object
```

We just have a *value*, not a reference (*Remember, a reference is a resolved name binding*).

---

<sup>(1)</sup>**NOTE:** On ECMAScript 5 *Strict Mode*, the `this` value will be `undefined` for **all** the cases described where the `this` value is set implicitly to the Global object.

This was made as a *security measure* mostly due the fact that people often forgot to use the `new` operator when invoking constructor functions, causing a bad behavior and pollution on the global scope.

For example:

```
function Foo () {
  this.prop = 'foo';
}
Foo(); // no `new` operator, boom!
```

As you known now, the `Foo` reference doesn't have a direct *base object*, `this` will point to the global object and it will unintentionally create a property on it.

On Strict Mode, the code would simply give you a `TypeError`, because the `this` value would be `undefined`.

Also as you may remember in the beginning I mentioned that the Reference Type has a third component, the `strict` flag.

Your original example:

```
(f=foo.bar)();
```

Would probably not even work on Strict Mode, because assignments to undeclared identifiers (such as `f` *seems*) are disallowed, (another security measure to avoid global object pollution).

More info:

- [Strict Mode](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/es5-chapter-2-strict-mode/)

Answer (score 3):

In the first 3 examples you use the `foo` object and run its function, thus you get the context from which the function is run, an `Object`, the `foo` object.

In the last 2 examples you copy the `foo.bar` function to the variable `f` and execute it. In this case the function is executed from the global context, not from the `foo` Object context.
 It would be the same as declaring and running

```
  function f() { 
    console.log('this:' + this);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Referencing ECMA-262 (edition five) which is probably difficult to follow (emphasis added):

> #### 10.2.1.2 Object Environment Records
>
> Object environment records can be configured to provide their binding object as an implicit this value for use in function calls. This capability is used to specify the behaviour of With Statement (12.10) induced bindings. 
>   The capability is controlled by a  provideThis Boolean value that is associated with each object environment record.  **By default, the value of provideThis is false** for any object environment record.
>
> #### 10.2.1.2.6 ImplicitThisValue()
>
> Object Environment Records return undefined as their ImplicitThisValue unless their provideThis flag is true.
>
> 1. Let envRec be the object environment record for which the method was invoked.
> 2. If the provideThis flag of envRec is true, return the binding object for envRec.
> 3. Otherwise, **return undefined**.
>
> #### 10.4.3 Entering Function Code
>
> 1. If the function code is strict code, set the ThisBinding to thisArg.
> 2. Else **if thisArg is null or undefined, set the ThisBinding to the global object**.
>
> #### 10.4.1.1 Initial Global Execution Context
>
> The following steps are performed to initialize a global execution context for ECMAScript code C:
>
> 1. Set the VariableEnvironment to the Global Environment.
> 2. Set the LexicalEnvironment to the Global Environment.
> 3. **Set the ThisBinding to the global object.**
>
> #### 10.4.2 Entering Eval Code
>
> The following steps are performed when control enters the execution context for eval code:
>
> 1. If there is no calling context or if the eval code is not being evaluated by a direct call (15.1.2.1.1) to the eval function then,
>
>    1. Initialize the execution context **as if it was a global execution context** using the eval code as C as described in 10.4.1.1.
> 2. Else,
>
>    1. **Set the ThisBinding to the same value as the ThisBinding of the calling execution context.**
>
> #### 11.1.1 The this Keyword
>
> **The this keyword evaluates to the value of the ThisBinding** of the current execution context.
>
> #### 11.2.3 Function Calls
>
> The production CallExpression : MemberExpression Arguments is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let ref be the result of evaluating MemberExpression.
> 2. Let func be GetValue(ref).
> 3. Let argList be the result of evaluating Arguments, producing an internal list of argument values (see 11.2.4).
> 4. If Type(func) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
> 5. If IsCallable(func) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
> 6. If Type(ref) is Reference, then
>
>    1. If IsPropertyReference(ref) is true, then
>
>       1. **Let thisValue be GetBase(ref).**
>    2. Else, the base of ref is an Environment Record
>
>       1. **Let thisValue be the result of calling the ImplicitThisValue concrete method of GetBase(ref).**
> 7. Else, Type(ref) is not Reference.
>
>    1. **Let thisValue be undefined.**
> 8. Return the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method on func, providing thisValue as the this value and providing the list argList as the argument values.
>
> #### 12.10 The with Statement
>
> 1. Let oldEnv be the running execution context’s LexicalEnvironment.
> 2. Let newEnv be the result of calling NewObjectEnvironment passing obj and oldEnv as the arguments
> 3. **Set the provideThis flag of newEnv to true.**

`this` is assigned to the global object if:

1. *thisArg* is *null* or *undefined* when calling a function.  *thisArg* is set:

   1. By the first argument of `Function.prototype.apply` (15.3.4.3).
   2. By the first argument of `Function.prototype.call` (15.3.4.4).
   3. By the first argument of `Function.prototype.bind` (15.3.4.5) (not in ECMA252-3).
   4. By calling using the `MemberExpression Arguments` syntax, meaning:

      1. `foo(arguments)` is equivalent to `foo.call((function() { }()), arguments);` iff `foo` is callable and if you're not in a `with` statement.
      2. `foo.bar(arguments)` is equivalent to `foo.bar.call(foo, arguments)`, evaluating `foo` only once, iff `foo.bar` is callable.
2. The context is the global context, which occurs:

   1. In the default scope.
   2. In the scope of `eval` if it is being called directly.

> My question is, why does `f=foo.bar; f();` and `(f=foo.bar)();` assign 'this' to be the Global Object

This is detailed under section 11.2.3, step 6.a.i (6.1.1 above); `ref` is the `f` expression in your case (*not* its value), and `GetBase(ref).ImplicitThisValue()` is `undefined` (as a variable has an object environmental record as its base with `provideThis` set to `false` if that variable does not come from `with`).

Comment: Provided for overcompleteness.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the first three cases and the last two cases is that you're storing the bar function in a variable. Functions don't "know" that they're properties of an object. So in the last two cases, you're just calling regular functions.

In last two cases, you could make "this" refer to "foo" by using Function.call or function.apply

```
f.call(foo)
```

Call and apply allow you to control what "this" refers to inside the function you're calling.

While functions don't know whether they're attached to an object or not, they do know what scope they're declared in. There's lots of useful stuff you can do based on that. In the last example, you're creating a new scope by doing  (f = foo.bar)(), but it has no effect whatsoever.