# How define function in javascript in global context inside a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, global-variables, global

```
context = this
function test() {
  (function(cmd) {
    eval(cmd);
  }).call(context, 'function foo(){}');
};

test();
foo(); // => ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

how can I define a global function inside a function ? (using nodeJS)

Comment: define  a global function by adding it to ... `global` ... e.g `global.yourFunctionName = function (arg1, arg2, ... , argN) { function body goes here };`

Comment: no because i use this function client side too, I can't add global.foo

Comment: well, that would be useful information in the question :p

Comment: I try to reduce the problem more simply ^^ but if necessary I can developed^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical way to access the global object is calling a yielded value, e.g. from the comma operator.

```js
function a() {
  (0, function () {
    this.foo = function () { console.log("works"); };
  })();
}
a();
foo();
```

**UPDATE:**
Due to `strict mode` issues, here is another version (references: [(1,eval)('this') vs eval('this') in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107240/1-evalthis-vs-evalthis-in-javascript/9107304), [Cases where 'this' is the global Object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295175/cases-where-this-is-the-global-object-in-javascript)):

```js
"use strict";
function a() {
  (0, eval)('this').foo = function () { console.log("works"); };
}
a();
foo();
```

Comment: What the hell... This works ! but I don't undersand why?

Comment: @Matrix see for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295175/cases-where-this-is-the-global-object-in-javascript) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107240/1-evalthis-vs-evalthis-in-javascript/9107304)

Comment: your answer is amazing, it should be award you like 10 good answer! XD

Comment: @Matrix looking at the [second question i referenced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295175/cases-where-this-is-the-global-object-in-javascript) the comma seems even unnecessary here, a simple IIFE would be enough. However, the previously posted code would fail in `strict mode` on ES5. Therefore i added an update, which should also work on `strict mode`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `global` object in Node.JS:

```
function test() {
  eval('function foo() { return "this is global"; }');
  global.foo = foo;
};

test();

console.log(foo()); // this is global
```

Comment: I can't do this. Foo() is define in other file and be used server AND client side, it can't change, it define by `function foo()`, can't add "global"

Comment: @Matrix How is `Foo` defined in your other file? Is it global? Is it loaded alongside this script? Can you export the `Foo` function and `require` it in this script?

Comment: in other file is just define global like `function foo(){..}`. I don't use require() because it need syntaxe `module.export` (this is incompatible with client side), so I read file and eval() it

Comment: @Matrix to make it compatible on the client side, just use `if (typeof exports != "undefined") module.exports = Foo`. It's recommended not to use `eval` as it's slow and sometimes dangerous (also the contexts get wacky, as you've found out)

Comment: @Matrix If you really want to use eval, and `foo` is declared in the global context in your other file: after `eval`ing it in your function, just go `global.foo = foo;`, as I have reflected in the answer