# Arrow functions return this as the window object

Tags: javascript, this

In my program using the `function()` syntax is returning the `this` value of a target element, but using an arrow function returns the window object. How are each of these two functions getting their `this`?

```
function editTemplates() {

//sits within for loop

    clocksTemplate.gmt[i].addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      console.log(this); //returns window object
    });

    clocksTemplate.gmt[i].addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
      console.log(this); //returns element bound to clocksTemplate.gmt
    });
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with **arrow functions**, this should "retain the original meaning from the enclosing context". Is the enclosing context the event listener? or the function it sits within? According to my test, the enclosing context for the arrow function must be the Window object but I can't see how. With the **function() syntax** the enclosing function is meant to redefine the this value, which I'm assuming it is doing here within the `addEventListener` method. This topic has been discussed in depth [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952743/arrow-functions-why-does-this-print-the-global-object-to-the-console) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295175/cases-where-this-is-the-global-object-in-javascript) but I'm a JS newbie and I couldn't understand how this applied to my problem.

Comment: Arrow functions will bind `this` of current scope, while `addEventListener` will bind element as `this`

Comment: now the documentation is up to date and explicity says that can not be used for coding methods... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#cannot_be_used_as_methods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is perfectly normal & expected behaviour of arrow functions.

As the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) mentions about regular functions:

> every new function defined its own `this` value (a new object in the
>   case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode function calls, the
>   context object if the function is called as an "object method", etc.).

If it is required to override the value of this in a regular function, then instead of calling it directly, we can invoke it using `call()` or `apply()`.

So in your case of regular function, the callback function is getting invoked internally by `addEventListener` function using a `call()` or `apply()` with value of this set to element bound to `clocksTemplate.gmt`. It's a standard practice to use `call()` or `apply()` for invoking callbacks.

In case of the first function (arrow function), the `this` does not get assigned any new value. They can't be invoked using `call()` or `apply()` because arrow functions are anonymous. So it continues to have the value that was defined by the enclosing function `editTemplates()` and that happens to be `window`.

See below for code example:

```
// REGULAR FUNCTION

function editTemplates() {

    console.log(this)    // window
    var myVar = this;

    // sits within for loop

    clocksTemplate.gmt[i].addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {

        // new value assigned for 'this' as element bound to clocksTemplate.gmt

        console.log(this);    // returns element bound to clocksTemplate.gmt

        console.log(myVar);    // returns window
    });



// ARROW FUNCTION (Anonymous Functions)

function editTemplates() {

    console.log(this)    // returns window object
    var myVar = this;

    // sits within for loop

    clocksTemplate.gmt[i].addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {

        // No new value gets assigned to 'this'

        console.log(this); // returns window object

        console.log(myVar);    // returns window object

        // Saves the hassle of saving 'this' to another variable!
    });
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: You helped me understand how this is working, thanks! To anybody else mulling over the this problem, another way to get at the target of the event is to use the event.target method. In the above example it looks like this:

    clocksTemplate.gmt[i].addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        console.log(e.target);
    });

This isn't the answer to my question, but just a bit more info for future people reading this question

Comment: Am glad I could help. Please accept/upvote the answer if satisfied.